# Easiest way to remove or hide QEntity from a scene

Tags: python-3.x, qt, qt5, qt3d, pyside2

I want to solve a problem in **Qt5**/**Qt3D**. A users presses a button and then some `QEntity` disappears (is removed or hidden). That `QEntity`'s object is a child object of a root entity. What is an easiest way to implement that using **Python** and **PySide2** ?

Comment: You could keep a reference to the `QEntity` in a `QVector<QEntity*>`, or store a `QEntity*` referencing that specific entity directly.
You then call `entity->setEnabled(false)` to hide it (and true to show it). I don't post it as an aswer because I can't test code right now

Comment: @Florent Uguent: Thanks, however that does not work in **Python**.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the Python part

Comment: I am sorry and thank you for the answer. This does work in Python. I did not test it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Florent Uguet commented:

```py
entity.setEnabled(False)
```

hides `QEntity` from the scene and

```
entity.setEnabled(True)
```

shows it.